# How to find the equation of a parabola with only one solution and a point?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, conic-sections

I have been given the points $(5, 0)$ and $(10, 5)$. I'm also given that the $a$ value in $ax^2 \pm bx \pm c$ is $-1$. I have been trying to work out to how to do this, but, when I graph the parabola, I'm not getting the correct solution.

I've been staring at this problem for a long time, and I'm not certain how to solve it anymore. I'm not very mathematically inclined, so please forgive my naive question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=-x^2+bx+c$$
We know this satisfies $x=5, y=0$ and $x=10,y=5$

$$0=-25+5b+c$$
$$5=-100+10b+c$$

Then you can solve this system of simultaneous equations very easily.

Comment: It does intersect $(5,0)$, but not $(10, 5)$

Comment: So you are telling me that $y=-x^2+16x-55$ does not pass through those two points?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up on my calculations.